# How could I write something through handwriting on to my Electronjs desktop app

Tags: python, html5-canvas, electron, handwriting

I am developing a desktop application using electron js and have python backend. I want to write something on to my app through hand without keyboard and want to store this handwritten information into my database. Any suitable solution for this task??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries.
Checkout
https://github.com/jakubfiala/atrament.js (Tiny JS library for beautiful drawing and handwriting on the HTML Canvas).